# jquery append with dropdown option in disabled="disabled"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my normal html drop down menu I am setting the default selected option to disabled state using below code

```
<select id="sel_bank" name="sel_bak">
  <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Select Your product</option>
  <option>Mobile</option>
  <option>laptop</option>
</select>
```

I have one mor drop down menu where the options are getting populated depends upon first drop down selection.

```
<select id="sel_state" name="sel_state">
  <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Select Your brand</option>
</select>
```

and using below jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sel_bank").change(function() {
  var el = $(this) ;
   if(el.val() === "Mobile" ) {
     $("#sel_state").empty().append
     ("<option SELECTED>Select Your product</option>\
       <option>Samsung</option>\
       <option>Nokia</option>");
     }
   else if(el.val() === "laptop"){
     $("#sel_state").empty().append
          ("<option SELECTED>Select Your product</option>\
            <option>HP</option>\
            <option>Dell</option>");       
      }
  });   
});
```

Here also, I need to set the default selected option `Select Your product` as `disabled` similar to first.I have tried to put

```
("<option disabled="disabled"  SELECTED>Select Your product</option>\
  <option>HP</option>\
  <option>Dell</option>");
```

But that is not working. How to do it ?

**[FS FIDDLE SETUP](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopcr/wd46s/3/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wd46s/6/)***

You're emptying and then appending again. But you didn't add `disabled` option

```
     $("#sel_bank").change(function () {
         var el = $(this);
         if (el.val() === "Mobile") {
             $("#sel_state").empty().append("<option disabled='disabled' SELECTED>Select Your product</option>\
     <option>Samsung</option>\
<option>Nokia</option>");
         } else if (el.val() === "laptop") {
             $("#sel_state").empty().append

             ("<option disabled='disabled' SELECTED>Select Your product</option>\
     <option>HP</option>\
<option>Dell</option>");

         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `disable='disabled'` for default option and note that `use single quotes` .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#sel_bank").change(function() {
 var el = $(this) ;
 if(el.val() === "Mobile" ) {
    $("#sel_state").empty().append
    ("<option disabled='disabled' SELECTED>Select Your product</option>\
     <option>Samsung</option>\
<option>Nokia</option>");
    }
      else if(el.val() === "laptop" ) {
         $("#sel_state").empty().append

          ("<option disabled='disabled' SELECTED>Select Your product</option>\
     <option>HP</option>\
<option>Dell</option>");

      }
  });


});
```

[FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wd46s/5/)

Answer (score 1):

I use this.

```
$("#sel_state").empty().append($('<option>', {
   disabled: true,
   value: value,
   text: text
}));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.